# div into full screen with scroll

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

How to make a div into full screen with scroll ? This code work but the scroollbar doesn't appear :

html :

```
<div id="full_screen"></div>
```

css :

```
#full_screen {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: try adding overflow: scroll; to your css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `overflow:scroll;` to show the scroll. Because the default behaviour of scroll is `overflow:auto;`.

```css
#full_screen {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background:red;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.content{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="full_screen"><div class="content"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="full_screen"></div>
```

Here is the updated css. When the content in the div #full-screen is more than it can contain in the screen, then scroll will appear.

```
#full_screen {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
top: 0;
z-index: 10;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

}